# create a combination of selected columns in a df

Tags: r, dplyr

Let us start with this data frame. Lets call them`temp` and `ppt` columns for columns starting with `t and p` respectively.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, area = rnorm(4, 123), t_p25 = rnorm(4, 2), t_p30 = rnorm(4, 0.5), 
     t_m25 = rnorm(4, 3), p1 = rnorm(4, 7), p_1 = rnorm(4, 10), p2 = rnorm(4, 3), p_2 = rnorm(4, -1))
```

My ultimate goal is to create a column `W` which is a calculated as `W = temp * ppt * area * {other columns as well}`.

> > For example:
> >     `W_t_p25_p1   = t_p25 * p1  * area`
> >     `W_t_p25_p_1  = t_p25 * p_1 * area`
> >     `W_t_m25_p1   = t_m25 * p1  * area`
> >     `W_t_m25_p_1  = t_m25 * p_1 * area` and so on

This is how I need them ::

```
id area  W_t_p25_p1  W_p_25_p_1  W_p_25_p2  W_p_25_p_2  W_t_p30_p1  W_t_p30_p_1  W_p_25_p2  W_p_25_p_2  ... and so on
#   ##            #           #          #           #           #            #          #           #   and so on
```

It would be tedious doing it manually. I tried to solve it with `mutate_at` but .vars is the limitation. If only this could be done::

```
df %>% mutate_at( .vars1 = colnames(.)[grep("^t_", colnames(.)],
                  .vars2 = colnames(.)[grep("^p", colnames(.)],
                  .funs = calc.W( .vars1, .vars2 , area)
                 )
```

Is there a simpler way to do something like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution I can think of (you can adjust indices according to how many of lower case and upper case letters exist in your `df`:

```
egrid <- expand.grid(names(df)[3:5], names(df)[6:9])
result <- as.data.frame(apply(egrid, 1, function(x) df$area * df[[x[1]]] * df[[x[2]]]))

colnames(result) <- paste0('W_', egrid$Var1, egrid$Var2)
result <- cbind(df[, 1:2], result)
result

  id     area     W_aA       W_bA     W_cA     W_aB       W_bB     W_cB      W_aC       W_bC     W_cC       W_aD        W_bD        W_cD
1  1 122.6077 2004.342 1235.42437 3253.378 2882.802 1776.88439 4679.264  795.9592 490.608589 1291.973 -976.96029 -602.172981 -1585.76799
2  2 126.1399 1713.637  -62.30608 2147.569 2483.034  -90.28058 3111.795 1291.2969 -46.950231 1618.283  221.76815   -8.063262   277.92486
3  3 120.9471 1282.721   -9.47124 4080.824 1790.517  -13.22066 5696.317  682.9681  -5.042838 2172.781 -159.77938    1.179764  -508.31898
4  4 121.7203 1634.049  392.82541 2938.293 2262.283  543.85269 4067.961  833.1827 200.297098 1498.201   13.87204    3.334838    24.94424
```

Comment: thank you Gopala, I have updated the question as my real df col names exists. Do you think you answer will still be the solution ?

Comment: It works fine. Although, you may want to adjust column names to suit your taste through that `paste0()`.